# sha256sum results for Kubuntu 15.10 DVD

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10

I have already burned the DVD from the ISO for Kubuntu 15.10.iso image. ISO verifies fine. But I read we are to verify the DVD also. I ran:

```
$ sha256sum /dev/cdrom
758061ca3be30128dca74e3f73b5dd6e76fb5047c0c4e0743f22786fb0a02dd0  /dev/cdrom
```

The only thing is, the download site tells you how to do the checksum, but there is no listing of what the hash response should be. I checked the entire site I believe.

Can someone please share the correct hash response for Kubuntu 15.10 64bit ISO? And provide  link to where it is officially listed please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sha256sum hash result of your /dev/cdrom must the same as the hash of your ISO

<strike>sha256sum /dev/cdrom</strike>

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom | head -c $(wc -c < kubuntu-15.10*.iso) | sha256sum -
```

and

```
sha256sum kubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

must return the same result

the correct hash = `9e5eb424eabfd9b2d193d8c34eca7b48ad944b90c0de0bdcbb638563c14c4d2b`
[Source](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/15.10/release/SHA256SUMS)

Comment: You are correct I believe. I got that correct hash for the ISO, but 758061ca3be30128dca74e3f73b5dd6e76fb5047c0c4e0743f22786fb0a02dd0  /dev/cdrom
for the DVD hash. I event ran it again and same hash. Im using xfburn in Xubuntu. Maybe I need a different burner software. Im out of ideas. I will mark you correct though, after a while. Wanna see what others say.

Comment: It is also not very clear that the hash for the DVD and iso should be the same.

Comment: An ISO file (or ISO image) is a perfect representation of the whole disc. so they must have the same hash at all times.
I googled a bit and it seems xfburn have trouble finalizing a disc/closing session after a burn , which makes the DVD useless and not readable.

Comment: Hmmm. could not get right hash for dvd in xfburn so I tried K3B and it givem me d7559c90efece2b38021804cc34011eb2cb161fff2afe6894985083bd41232d5. Ill open a seperate question for this I guess Thanks again @Houssem-Guesmi

Comment: @houssemguesmi No. Hashing a device is just wrong. Not what you do.

Comment: @HeatherBrown why is the official download page saying we should do this then? and are you saying my DVD I burned should be fine?

Comment: It says to verify the iso file. Verifying the device is different. Your burning software should verify the disc in the finalizing stage. The disc should be fine

Comment: Like the answer below says, in many cases an ISO will be padded with zeros at the end before being burned until its size matches a multiple of 16 sectors (or 16 * 2048 B); so it's actually the opposite, in most cases hashing the device will return a different hash than hashing the ISO.

Answer (score 2):

The checksums of ISO and DVD should be the same.
But most optical media return more bytes than were recorded.
This alters the checksum result, of course.

You need to restrict reading from DVD to the size of the ISO,
See in
  https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#verify
the third paragraph "The problem with the verification of written
optical media ..."

The same amount of bytes as in the ISO file must yield the
same checksum. Else the DVD is not good.