# Brasero got stuck in image checksum after burning, is the burning process compromised?

Tags: iso, dvd, burning

I was burning the iso image of the last Ubuntu distro with Brasero, and it got stuck doing the checksum thing it does after burning the image.
So I canceled and it finished doing whatever it was doing.
Apparently everything's fine (I've disable the image checksum plugin for future occasions), but I'm worried the data might be corrupted or something.
Can I verify if the DVD image and the data burned to it are OK?

Edit:
OK, the DVD is corrupted or something, because my laptop says it's empty, with no data.
So I guess I'll have to burn the image again in another disc.
Any recommendations on how to avoid spoiling further discs because of these silly behaviours?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sha256sum results for Kubuntu 15.10 DVD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712170/sha256sum-results-for-kubuntu-15-10-dvd)

Comment: Captcha does not let me post an answer. So as comment: Try other media from other brands and of other type (e.g. DVD-R versus DVD+R versus DVD+RW). If several different media fail, then the drive has probably reached its end of life.